# In a right triangle $ABC$ calculate the length of $BC$ if $AP=PC=MC=1$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, angle

In a right triangle $ABC$ where the angle $ABC = 90^{\circ}$, on the side $BC$ is placed a point $P$ and on $AC$ a point $M$ so that $BM$ and $AC$ are perpendicular and $AP=PC=MC=1$. What would be the length of $BC$?

No plot is given so I plotted it in GeoGebra.

I drew the segment $MP$ to create the isosceles triangle $MPC$ but I did not get any result. I also tried to create the isosceles triangles $MPC$, $APC$, and the right triangles $BMC$, $BMA$ and $ABP$. I also placed a point at the intersection of $BM$ and $AP$ called $D$, with this point I created another right triangle $ADM$.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

[image: triangle on geogebra]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you did, label the intersection point of $BM$ and $AP$ as $D$. Since $\lvert AP\rvert = \lvert PC\rvert = 1$, then $\triangle APC$ is isosceles and, thus,

$$\measuredangle PAC = \measuredangle PCA = \gamma \;\;\to\;\; \measuredangle APC = 180^{\circ} - 2\gamma, \; \measuredangle APB = 2\gamma \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Also, let

$$\lvert AM\rvert = x, \;\; \lvert AD\rvert = y \;\;\to\;\; \lvert DP\rvert = 1 - y \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

In $\triangle ADM$, since $\measuredangle AMD = 90^{\circ}$, then $\measuredangle ADM = 90^{\circ} - \gamma$. Also, by opposite angles, we have $\measuredangle BDP = 90^{\circ} - \gamma$. Thus, from \eqref{eq1A}, we get

$$\measuredangle DBP = 180^{\circ} - \measuredangle BDP - \measuredangle APB = 180^{\circ} - (90^{\circ} - \gamma) - 2\gamma = 90^{\circ} - \gamma \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Since $\measuredangle BDP = \measuredangle DBP$, then $\triangle BDP$ is isosceles, with using \eqref{eq2A} that $\lvert BP\rvert = \lvert DP\rvert = 1 - y$. This then gives that

$$\lvert BC \rvert = \lvert BP\rvert + \lvert PC\rvert = (1 - y) + 1 = 2 - y \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Next, from the first part of \eqref{eq1A}, we get that $\triangle DAM \sim \triangle  BCM$ so, by ratios of similar sides, we have

$$\frac{1}{2 - y} = \frac{x}{y} \;\;\to\;\; x = \frac{y}{2 - y} \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Thus, then also

$$\lvert AC\rvert = \lvert AM\rvert + \lvert MC\rvert = \frac{y}{2 - y} + 1 = \frac{y + (2 - y)}{2 - y} = \frac{2}{2 - y} \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Since $\triangle ACB \sim \triangle BCM$ then, from \eqref{eq2A}, \eqref{eq4A} and \eqref{eq5A} we get

$$\frac{\frac{2}{2-y}}{2 - y} = \frac{2 - y}{1} \;\;\to\;\; 2 = (2 - y)^3 \;\;\to\;\; 2 - y = \sqrt[3]{2} \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

Finally, using \eqref{eq4A}, we have

$$\lvert BC\rvert = \sqrt[3]{2} \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

Answer (score 0):

In the Given construction, The Right Triangles $ABC$ and $BMC$ are similar, we can see that $Angle(BAC) = Angle(MBC)$. Due to which we arrive

$$\frac {BM^2}{AB^2} = \frac {MC^2}{BC^2}$$

Now, making use of the conditions $PC = AP = MC = 1$. Also, $BC = (1+BP)$, $BM^2 = (BP+1)^2 - 1^2$ (from right triangle $BMC$), $AB^2 = 1^2 - BP^2$ (from right triangle $APB$). Solving the cubic equation for $BP$, we get $BP = (\sqrt [3]2 - 1)$ and $BC =\sqrt[3]2$.

Comment: Using your approach, & $1 - BP^2 = (1-BP)(1+BP)$, I get that $\frac{BM^2}{AB^2}=\frac{MC^2}{BC^2}$ becomes $\frac{(BP+1)^2-1}{(1-BP)(1+BP)} = \frac{1}{(BP+1)^2}\;\to\; ((BP+1)^2-1)(BP + 1) = 1 - BP \;\to\; BP^3 + 3BP^2 + 3BP - 1 = 0$. Although cubics can always be explicitly solved , perhaps you can add details about how you determined that $BP = 0.75(\sqrt{2} - 1)$. In particular, assuming I didn't make any mistakes, I get the LHS is about $0.2515$ rather than $0$. Also, your result conflicts with mine, so perhaps I made a mistake, but I have double-checked, although I will check again.

Comment: I made a mistake. I missed that $(1+BP)$ expression, which reduced it to a quadratic equation hence the result. I will edit my answer. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: BTW your answer is right, it solves the cubic equation.